# How do I render an Augmented Matrix with MathJax?

Tags: latex, matrix, render, mathjax

I'm looking for a way to render an [Augmented Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) in MathJax. In addition, I'd like to do things like right-align the text in the columns.

I found a LaTeX [solution](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/) for this, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with MathJax - or even if its possible.  I notice that the \makeatletter command is not supported by MathJax.

Is it possible to  do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(I think this should belong on http://tex.stackexchange.com)

If you don't need fancy formatting, [the code in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Augmented_matrix&action=edit) works fine with MathJax.

```
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
    16 & 32 & 64 & 128 \\
    256 & 512 & 1024 & 2048
  \end{array}\right]
$$
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - I had been using bmatrix instead of array, which doesn't take any arguments.  Thanks!